# Unable to connect to Template Builder : Upgrade from Tridion 2011 to Web8.5

Tags: web8.5, templating, template-builder

After upgrading the CMS from Tridion 2011 to Web8.5 Template builder throws an exception below when you click on the `Building blocks` folder in any publication.

```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object  
    <detail>
       <Message>
         <Line>Object reference not set to an instance of an 
   object.</Line>
      </Message>
      <StackTrace>
     <StackFrame method="GetBundleSchemaID" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService" 
/>
      <StackFrame method="AddBundleSubtypeToVirtualFolders" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService" />
      <StackFrame method="GetList" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService" />
     </StackTrace>
   </detail>
```

I know Tridion 2011 does not support Bundles, but I assumed the upgrade script would have added in a Schema for it. Does anyone know a workaround to resolve this? is there is a way to add this in manually or is this something for SDL support?

Since my CMS DB(ORACLE)was upgraded from T2011,  it does not contain any Bundles and I do not intend to create any bundles for now. However when I attempt I get an error `unknown Virtual Folder Type: Virtual Folder Cartridge is not registered for this type.`

Comment: 1. What was the exact version of T2011 upgraded from Is it 2011 SP1 or T2011 HR2?
2. During the DB upgrade did find an issue?

Comment: T2011 HR2 was the  exact version, there were no problems with the DB upgrade.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Since direct upgrade from 2011 to 8.5 is not supported: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C

Comment: The upgrade was in stages, first from  T2011 HR2 ->  T2013  and then T2013 -> T2013 SP1 HR1 and then finally  T2013SP1 HR1-> Web8.5. SDL provides scripts for each of these  steps, so yes there is no direct upgrade from 2011 to web 8.5, but there is an indirect upgrade.

Comment: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C

Answer (score 1):

Bundle Schemas are not necessary for creating Bundles, they are instead used for defining a Process Definition for Workflow, etc. I wonder why are they even mentioned in the error message, do you have any Bundle Schemas in your CM? Also, your question is lacking a very important piece of information, and that is, when do you get this message? Does it appear immediately when you open the builder and connect to an environment? Or does it appear when you open a PT/CT, or when you run a certain CT/PT? If yes, what does your templating code do?

For starters make sure to use Web 8.5's Template Builder not 2011, and please update your question with additional information.

Comment: I have updated my question and I am using Web8.5's Template builder, i am not getting this error when i try to create a bundle, i get a different error when i try to create a bundle which is simply `unknown  Virtual Folder Type: Virtual Folder Cartridge is not registered for this type.`